# Is there anyone who can figure out why popups in my map function are not coming up on the map on click in R? Using leaflet

Tags: r, dictionary, leaflet, polygon

I'm creating a map with leaflet with zip code and county polygons. I would like for the values for columns "GEOID10" and "percent" from data set df to popup when I click on their respective zip code polygons. I don't get an error message when I run this code and the output is still a map, but I am unable to get any popups to show up. Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong? I have tried moving the `addPolygons(txcounties...)` after the `addPolygons(df...)` but nothing changed. Forgive me, I am a total R novice and just learned this summer.

```
map1 <- leaflet() %>%
        addProviderTiles ("CartoDB.Positron") %>% 
        setView (-99.9, 31.97, zoom = 5) %>%
        addPolygons(data = zips, fill = "white", fillOpacity = 0, weight = 0, stroke = FALSE)%>% 
        addPolygons(data = txcounties, fill = "white" , fillOpacity = 0, weight = 1, color =. 
           "black", label = txcounties$NAME) %>% 
        addPolygons(data = df, color = ~pal (percent), stroke = F, fillOpacity = 0.6, weight = 
           1, label = ~paste0(percent), popup = ~paste0(
           GEOID10, "<br>",
           "Zip Code: ", format(`GEOID10`), "<br>",
           "% of NSLP enrolled in P-EBT : ", round(`percent`, 2), "<br>"))%>% 
        addPolygons(data = txcounties, fill = "white" , fillOpacity = 0, weight = 1, color =. 
           "black", label = txcounties$NAME) %>% 
        addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = pal, values = df$percent, title = "percent 
        enrolled")
map1
```